# MySQL row is shown although the value is NULL

Tags: mysql

I have two tables – `tmst_paket` and `tmst_paketdata` – and a query like this:

```
SELECT
      p.id_paket,
      p.id_user,
      p.nama_paket,
      p.id_instansi,
      p.id_relasi,
      p.status_progress,
      p.status_paket,
      p.from_status,
      p.to_status,
      COALESCE(sum(pd.kuantitas))total_buku,
      COALESCE(sum(pd.total_hargaitem))total_hargabuku,
      DATE_FORMAT(p.tgl_buat,'%d-%m-%Y') created_date_formatted,
      DATE_FORMAT(p.tgl_modif,'%d-%m-%Y') modified_date_formatted
FROM
      tmst_paket p
JOIN
      tmst_paketdata pd
ON
      p.id_paket = pd.id_paket
ORDER BY 
      p.id_paket
```

the query succeeds when the tables have values, but if the tables are empty, it still shows the row, although the value is `NULL`. I’ve been trying to add a condition like

```
WHERE
   pd.id_paket IS NOT NULL
```

but the result is still the same; the row is shown with a value null. How can I make the result an empty list?

Comment: *Which* value/column is NULL? That is the one that needs to be filtered (WHERE) on.

Comment: Do you have  not null constraint in the id_paket columns? Also, check that the table is empty. As you are using an inner join then there should be no rows returned by your query when either table is empty. to check the table is empty do select count(*) on each table individually. you should get zero on at least one of them.

Comment: add some data and table in the http://sqlfiddle.com so that it could be tested.